# Difference between generic type constraints 'struct, Enum' and 'Enum'?

Tags: c#

What is the differene between

- `class Example<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, Enum`
- `class Example<TEnum> where TEnum : Enum`

Sorry if this is a stupid question, just want to understand.

Comment: C# doesn't have a notnull type or keyword. Have you defined something called notnull?

Comment: @ShamPooSham it does since C# version 8 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: Struct constraint says it's a value type; notnull constraint doesn't mean that, because (IIUC - haven't toyed with those much) reference types can be not-nullable too. Enum constraint does what it says on the tin: enums are value types, but not all value types are enums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Enum` constraint was added in C# 7.3. The `struct` constraint is much older. It's probably an artifact of the implementation, but the `Enum` constraint by itself does not imply `struct`.

> **The oddities of the Enum constraint**
>
> There is one very interesting caveat with the `Enum` constraint: the constraint does not imply [by] itself that the `T` is a struct. Moreover, you can actually combine the Enumconstraint with the `class` constraint:
>
> ```cs
> // The only valid TEnum type is `System.Enum`
> public static void Foo<TEnum>() where TEnum : class, Enum
> { }
> static void Main(string[] args)
> {
>    // Error 'EnumLong' must be a class
>    Foo<EnumLong>();
>    // Ok, but why would you do that?!?!?
>    Foo<System.Enum>();
> ```
>
> The combination `where TEnum: class, Enum` makes no sense and the only reasonable way to use the `Enum` constraint is to use it with the `struct` constraint: `where TEnum: struct, Enum`.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-new-generics-constraints-in-c-7-3/